# How did Sir Isaac Newton develop and formulate the famous binomial theorem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

After completing combination, I have started to read Binomial Theorem. My book only mentioned about Pascal's Triangle. And the formula was then given straightforward. But how did Sir Issac Newton actually develop this theorem?? How did he formulate all these??? Please help.

Comment: Do you mean the straight binomial formula or the generalization to non-integer exponents credited to Newton ?

Comment: To expand on Yves' comment, the basic binomial theorem for positive, integer powers is typically attributed to Pascal and Yves himself provides a nice answer for that. Newton generalized this to rational exponents. The easiest way to do so is to apply [Taylor's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem) the function $(1+x)^p$, where $p\in\mathbb Q$ or even in $\mathbb R$. I'm not sure that this is how Newton approached the problem, though.

Comment: Fortunately, we don't have to speculate about this.  Newton described his thought process in a letter to Henry Oldenburg, which you can read [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/store/10.1002/9781118096864.app4/asset/app4.pdf;jsessionid=AEF4672B3C0725420AA4BFFB0A835D49.f01t04?v=1&t=i3y88qg7&s=cd70c641016906c21e023567f1a238a0fe85b2e1).  Interestingly, he started by essentially looking at expressions for $\int_0^x(1-t^2)^{n/2}\,dt,$ which were already known for even $n.$  He then guessed the interpolating formula for odd $n.$  Only then did he consider...

Comment: ... the simpler problem of expanding $(1-x^2)^{n/2}.$  He was easily able to see the generalization to other fractional powers.

Comment: @WillOrrick what do you think of my proof?

Comment: @WillOrrick, nice. it would be if you could post your comment as an answer. what passes for answer for this dont make no sense. they are just repeating the proof of binomial theorem  for integer exponents. oldenburg they never heard of. struik's math source book we don't know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

About the Binomial Theorem.

When expanding the powers of a binomial by hand and grouping the terms by identical powers, it is not very hard to observe the pattern:

$$(x+y)^0=1$$
$$(x+y)^1=x+y$$
$$(x+y)^2=x^2+2xy+y^2$$
$$(x+y)^3=x^3+3x^2y+3xy^2+y^3$$
$$(x+y)^4=x^4+4x^3y+6x^2y^2+4xy^3+y^4$$
$$\dots$$

- the expansion is the sum of all $n+1$ possible products of the form $x^iy^j$, with $i+j=n$.
- the shape of Pascal's triangle clearly appears as the number of terms goes linearly increasing.
- the basic recurrence relation between Pascal's numbers appears with the following expansion:

$$\begin{align}(x+y)(x+y)^3
&=x^4+3x^3y+3x^2y^2+xy^3\ +\\
&\ \ \ \ \ \underline{\ \ \ \ +\ \ x^3y+3x^3y^2+3xy^3+y^4}\\
&=x^4+4x^3y+6x^2y^2+4xy^3+y^4
\end{align}$$

You get a new line of coefficients by adding the last line to itself shifted by one position, so that $C_m^{n+1}=C_{m-1}^n+C_m^n$.

All of this is rather straightforward to establish. More interesting is the link with combinatorial analysis.

If you expand $(x+y)^n$ without regrouping the terms,

$$(x+y)^0=1$$
$$\begin{align}(x+y)^1&=x\\
&+y\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}(x+y)^2&=xx\\
&+xy+yx\\
&+yy\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}(x+y)^3&=xxx\\
&+xxy+xyx+yxx\\
&+xyy+yxy+yyx\\
&+yyy\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}(x+y)^4&=xxxx\\
&+xxxy+xxyx+xyxx+yxxx\\
&+xxyy+xyxy+xyyx+yxxy+yxyx+yyxx\\
&+yyxy+yyyx+xyyy+yxyy\\
&+yyyy\end{align}$$
$$\dots$$
you see that there are $2^n$ terms, and you observe that all combinations of $i$ letters $x$ and $j$ letters $y$ (with $i+j=n$) can be grouped as $x^iy^j$, hence
$$C_m^n=\binom nm.$$
At the same time, you see a bell-shaped histogram appear, that prefigures the Gaussian curve.

Comment: Are you sure sir that you have written all things correctly? Just check $(x + y)^3$ ?

Comment: No surprise, all of this was done by hand. The primary goal is to explain the working principles, not to supply the results. You didn't answer my first comment, which makes it impossible to return the answer you expect.

Comment: Sorry sir for my arm-chair criticizings. Really you have done a tedious job. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. I will fix any typo you spot.

Answer (score 0):

Here, $(x+y)^n$ can be written as $(x+y)(x+y)(x+y)......n..times$

We have to find the coefficient of $x^by^c$ or $a$ in the term $ax^by^c$ in the expansion of $(x+y)^n$ where $(b+c)=n$. So first we will have to find number of ways we can get $x^b$ and we can get it by finding the number of ways we can multiply $(x+y)$, $b$ times which is same as selecting $b$ $(x+y)$ out of $n$ $(x+y)$s which is equal to $n \choose b$. Now we have to find number of ways we can get $y^c$ from the remaining $(n-b)$, $(x+y)$, which is $n-c \choose c$=$c \choose c$=1.

So the total number of ways we can get $x^by^c$ is $n \choose b$ and since $(b+c)=n$, it is also equal to $n \choose c$.

Pretty simple Proof.

Answer (score 0):

There's actually nothing to prove in the binomial theorem other than that the series developed is well-defined. (I take it we're talking about the cases when the index is *not* a positive integer, so that we have an infinite series -- and this is the case usually attributed to Newton since the positive integral case had been known since ancient times).

Now Newton did not *prove* this theorem, but used it, and felt justified by a combination of physical insight (he was trying to work out some plane areas) and blind faith to work out when the series makes sense.

In sum, apart from issues of convergence, the binomial theorem is actually a *definition* -- namely an extension of the case when the index is a positive integer to more general indices. (As you may know, the former case can be proved by induction.)

As for a *proof* of the limits within which this generalisation is valid, I think the Norwegian mathematician Niels Abel was the first to supply one. Of course, *you* may justify that if $|x|\lt 1,$ then $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\binom{r}{k}x^k}$$ converges, by the ratio test, where $r$ is any real number.